# In Star Trek 2 (movie) The Wrath Of Khan, why does Khan wear the federation emblem?

Tags: star-trek, federation, the-wrath-of-khan

Watching the film again, I noticed that once Khan gets on the bridge of the Reliant, he has a Federation emblem on a neck chain. Previously on the planet Khan was well covered (although it might appear in an earlier scene).

[image]

Here it is on Scottie's belt;

[image]

Some of Khan's crew wear ornament, although more in keeping with their gritty, weathered, simple eco time on Ceti Alpha V.

[image]

Q. So my question is, if Khan hates Kirk with a vengeance and presumably the Federation for marooning him on a remote planet for 20+ years (leading to the death of his wife), and he originates from a pre-Federation time period, why would he wear the Federation's emblem on his throat? Is it possibly a ritualistic thing - brandishing the teeth or bones of an enemy he has defeated for machismo / domination?

Thanks

Comment: I'd say it's a **trophy** as you indicated in your last line. Like a shark's tooth / bear claw thing

Comment: Khan's late wife was a Starfleet officer before she joined him on Ceti Alpha V. Maybe that particular ornament was a possession of hers, and he wears it as a memento?

Comment: Many thanks both of you. That latter has got to clinch it. Had no idea his wife was Starfleet - was that nugget from the original TV series? Makes complete sense - even the fact that it is broken top left edge (possibly signifying her demise, or maybe it was damaged at that time). It is the level of detail art / set directors / writers consider (I worked in TV for a few years).   I would say this is Answered then.

Comment: Praxis - appreciate you pointing me to a similar article - its not a duplicate though. My interest is in 'why' Khan (who appears to hate Kirk and the Federation) is wearing its insignia? The older question is "Who did he get it from" with comments rambling off into what its made of and differences to the original TV series. This doesn't interest me and I did search the board before I asked my question.  I think Royal Canadian Bandit has hit the mark... its a homage to his dead wife, a Starfleet officer who has died.  Thanks for the input though.